# Is there any free CMS for screen reader compatibility for admin?

Tags: php, content-management-system, accessibility, screen-readers

Is there any free CMS to operate a small business website/blog with screen reader compatibility where a blind person can update the content and other things via CMS administration using screen reader software and keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

I used [Drupal](http://drupal.org) several years ago with jaws for windows as both an administrator and content author with good results. For an IBM article on Drupal accessibility see [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/i-osource7/) For info on accessibility from the Drupal site see [this](http://drupal.org/node/394094)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Plone.
http://plone.org

It's been developed to meet and exceed the WCAG-AA accessibility standard.  It will work with Jaws or your choice of screen readers.

I work with the World Institute on Disability whose website is developed in Plone.
http://wid.org